# Selector bad behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments, selector

In my project i have a fragment with 1 ImageButton, whose "src" attribute is a selector.

Here the XML layout (foo.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_vote_down"
    android:id="@+id/foo_btn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here the selector (ic_vote_down.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_blue" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_red" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

The fragment body is almost empty: i only do this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foo, container, false);
    //v.findViewById(R.id.foo_btn).setEnabled(false);
    return v;         
}
```

I expect to see a blue image when the app starts and a red image if i disable the button, but i get the opposite result. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code seems fine. check the actual drawables if they are swapped for some reason.

Comment: @AshwiniBhangi i restarted eclipse and now it's all ok. Wow, i tried everything (clean, rebuild, rename, check, double-check and so on) but not restarting. It sounds like a not-so-uncommon eclipse joke :)

Comment: yes. when things don't work always clean & rebuild, also refresh your folder if files have changed  :)